# Rselenium returns many more elements than expected

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I would like to find the name of the different hockey tournament/leagues from this [page](http://www.oddsportal.com/results/#hockey). The problem is that I end up with close to 8000 elements, which I dont see why.

```
library(RSelenium)
rs <- rsDriver()
remote <- rs$client

remote$navigate("http://www.oddsportal.com/results/#hockey")
elems <- remote$findElements("css selector", "#archive-tables > table a") 
# tournaments <- unlist(sapply(elems, function(x) x$getElementText())) This takes very long time due to the number of elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually lots  of elements of the type you have chosen to search!

One way to see it is---my favorite tool---is to install SelectorGadgets (a Chrome extension), and try clicking on the element that you were trying to scrape (or better, just type in #archive-tables a).

You will see that lots of other hyperlinks in other categories, such as soccer, tennis, basketball, etc, which the RSelenium has no way of distinguishing based on your orders, flare up in yellow.

The following solution is naive but it's quick. I like rvest, because I love using piping and it's so much more intuitive to me---install package rvest, and then

```
library(rvest)
odds_portal <- read_html("http://www.oddsportal.com/results/#hockey")
temp <- odds_portal %>% html_nodes("#archive-tables a") %>% html_text()
a <- which(temp=="Hockey")
b <- which(temp=="Handball")
temp[a:(b-1)]
```

I think the resulting 320 elements are closer to what you wanted, although you'd have to filter out some of them e.g. Asia. Let me know if this doesn't turn out well.